# Conditionally populating a new column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
| Binary | Status | Inception | New Status |
+--------+--------+-----------+------------+
|      1 | Raising|      2016 |            |
|      1 | Raising|      2017 |            |
|      0 | Failed |      2018 |            |
|      1 | Closed |      2021 |            |
|      1 | Raising|      2020 |            |
```

I have been populating the `New Status` column as following:

```
q = df.query('Binary == 1 and Inception <= 2022 - 3 and Status != "Closed" and Status != "Failed"')
my_query_index = q.index
my_query_index
df.iloc[my_query_index, 3] = "Closed"
df
```

However, I would like to do this in a more dynamic way, using a `<` in the first case and a `<=` in the second case. In this case, if todays date happens to be during the first half of the year, I will use the query

```
q = df.query('Binary == 1 and Inception < 2022 - 3 and Status != "Closed" and Status != "Failed"')
my_query_index = q.index
my_query_index
df.iloc[my_query_index, 3] = "Closed"
df
```

and if todays date happens to be in the second half of the year, use

```
q = df.query('Binary == 1 and Inception <= 2022 - 3 and Status != "Closed" and Status != "Failed"')
my_query_index = q.index
my_query_index
df.iloc[my_query_index, 3] = "Closed"
df
```

I would like to replace `Inception` (in the code) with `today`, given that `today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. I am not sure how to incorporate these two cases into the code and am also not sure how to incorporate it into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use str format for the query

```
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
half_year = '2022-06-01'

if today < half_year:
    query = 'Binary == 1 and Inception < 2022 - 3 and Status != "Closed" and Status != "Failed"'
else:
    query = 'Binary == 1 and Inception <= 2022 - 3 and Status != "Closed" and Status != "Failed"'
```

then your regular code

```
q = df.query(query)
my_query_index = q.index
my_query_index
df.iloc[my_query_index, 3] = "Closed"
df
```